# what is the difference between starting a command with nohup and &?

Tags: shell, command-line, nohup

nohub  and & seem to have a similar effect on the surface, they both start processes without occupying the shell from which they have been started, how do they differ on a deeper level?

Answer (score 1):

**Nohup**

- command will be immune to hangup signals
- Runs without a tty

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

**&**

- Command is placed in the backgroud
- You can still get back to the command (from same shell) using 'fg'

> If a command is followed by a & and job control is not active, the
>   default standard input for the command is the empty file /dev/null. 
>   Otherwise, the invoked command inherits the  file  descriptors of the
>   calling shell as modified by redirections